# Outputting Next Available Date from JSON Response

Tags: javascript, json, eventbrite

I am working with a `JSON` response from the Eventbrite API to display the 'next' event tour date. This date would be calculated automatically by looking at the current time and finding the next event that is after the current time.

Here is the `JSON` response that I need to parse:

https://jsfiddle.net/dgc223/k9dbvzoo/

If I were checking it right now, I would want the date to be returned from line 277 `(2017-11-11T11:00:00)`. If I were checking it in a couple hours, I would want to return line 350 `(2017-12-09T11:00:00)`, since that is the next available date for the tour.

The current script I have (below) returns the FIRST date of the series from a `JSON` response above. However, I need to modify it to return the NEXT Tour date, after accounting for the current time. This way the script can be more informative by telling the user the next available date of the tour.

```
<script>
  $.getJSON('eventbrite_api2.php', {
    eventid: '35719663475',
    function: 'events'
  }, function(response) {
    var date = new Date(response.start.utc); //this formats the date to local 
    time zone
    date.toString();
    event_start = date.toLocaleString('en-US', {
      weekday: 'long',
      day: 'numeric',
      month: 'long',
      year: 'numeric',
      hour: 'numeric',
      hour12: true,
      timeZone: "America/New_York"
    }); //this formats the date to eastern time zone, and makes some other formatting of the date
    var content = "<h4>" + response.name.text + "</h4><p>The next event starts " + event_start + "</p>" + "<p>" + "<img width=\"350\" src=" + response.logo.original.url + "</img>";
    $("#eventbrite").append(content);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would filter out any events that had already passed and then use the first if there was one. So the function that processes the response would look like this.

```
function (response) {
  var date = new Date();
  var upcoming = response.events.filter(function (event) {
    // just compare the UTC representation
    var start = new Date(event.start.utc);
    return start > date;
  });
  if (upcoming.length) {
    //next event is upcoming[0]; Do what you want with it
  } else {
    //no events upcoming
  }
}
```

The filter function for javascript arrays takes a test function and returns a new array with only the elements in the second array that returned true when passed into the test function.

Comment: Thank you. I am getting the following error though: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Comment: Hmm. Your JSFiddle showed an object structured like `{ pagination: {...}, events: [...] }` You need to call filter on the events array. Make sure you are executing your callback on the whole response that contains that array and not just one event.

Comment: Thank you - my callback before didn't have the whole response. Now, though I am getting "TypeError: start.UTC is not a function"

Comment: @DanielC sorry about that. I wrote my answer too quick I guess. I edited the code. Just compare the dates themselves and it should work.

Comment: thank you, I got that too. Appreciate all your help!